# Unlimited stack in php foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is it possible to have stacks without repeating foreach loop from the code below.

```
<?php
$stack1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i','j'); 
$lp1 = 0;
$id1 = 0;
foreach($stack1 AS $v){         
    $lp1++;
    if($lp1==3){
      break;
    }else{
      $id1++;
      echo 'Stack-1 => '.$v.'<br>';      
    }    
}
$stack2 = array_slice($stack1, $id1);
$lp2 = 0;
$id2 = 0;
foreach ($stack2 as $v2){
    $lp2++;
    if($lp2==3){
      break;
    }else{
      $id2++;
      echo 'Stack-2 => '.$v2.'<br>';
    }
}
$stack3 = array_slice($stack2, $id2);
$lp3 = 0;
$id3 = 0;
foreach ($stack3 as $v3){
    $lp3++;
    if($lp3==3){
      break;
    }else{
      $id3++;
      echo 'Stack-3 => '.$v3.'<br>';      
    }
}
?>
```

The size of the first stack stack1 is dynamic and could vary from time to time. I have no idea to make it work without repeating the foreach loop here. Please help.

Comment: You mean array_chunk?

Comment: I have no idea. That's why I am asking here. Please can you show how array_chunk would solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean but it will create the variables $stack1 -> $stack5 as arrays with two items each.

I use array_chunk to split the array and then create a new array with associative keys that I can extract to separate array variables.

```
$stack1 = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f','g','h','i','j'); 

$stacks = array_chunk($stack1, 2);

Foreach($stacks as $key => $stack){
    $new['stack' . ($key+1)] = $stack;
}
Extract($new);

Var_dump($stack1, $stack2, $stack3, $stack4, $stack5);
```

https://3v4l.org/t7ug6